# Integral of the form $e^{i K \sqrt{x^2+a^2}}/\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve integrals of the following form $$\int\frac{ {\rm e}^{\imath K \sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} {\rm d} x,$$

where $K$ and $a$ are real positive constants. Mathematica did not provide any solution so I have serious doubts whether it can be solved analytically. And yet, it looks so elementary?

Substituting the square root doesn't seem to help since for $p = \sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ we have $\frac{ {\rm d}p}{{\rm d}x} = \frac x p = \frac{\sqrt{p^2-a^2}}{p}$, leading to $$\int\frac{ {\rm e}^{\imath K p}}{\sqrt{p^2-a^2}} {\rm d} p.$$ We've linearlizted the exponent but the demoninator looks no better. Mathematica still gives up.

Somehow these square-root-of-sum-of-squares terms seem to call for a trigonometric substitution but I just cannot put my finger on what it might look like.

Is this a standard integral? Would someone have a clue whether it has an analytical solution or not?

**edit**: after Chappers' comment I had a look at the infinite indefinite integral and it seems this can be solved in closed form. Mathematica claims $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{ {\rm e}^{\imath K \sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} {\rm d} x = -\pi(Y_0(a K) + \jmath J_0(a K)),$$ where $J_0(z)$ and $Y_0(z)$ are the Bessel functions of the first and second kind, respectively. Unfortunately, I need the integral in a finite interval $[b,b+c]$, where both $b$ and $c$ can be arbitrary. I guess this means I need to integrate numerically.

Comment: Looks like something Bessel-ish.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. The Exp with something trigonometric-ish inside calls for Bessel. But I couldn't bring it in any Bessel integral form.

Comment: If we have a complex component then an integral should have a defined integration path on the Argand plain.  Is one defined?

Comment: I'm integrating over the real variable $x$. The integrand is complex but the integration variable is not. Might as well integrate real and imaginary part separately, in this case the question would be about $\int \frac{\cos[k\sqrt{x^2+a^2}]}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} {\rm d}x$. This would help as well.

Comment: With limits $-\infty$ and $\infty$ it is a standard integral, giving a Hankel function: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E10

Comment: @Chappers: Interesting, thanks! Though I don't quite see yet how I can bring it into the form of the Hankel integral. Unfortunately, I have to integrate over a finite interval that could be located anywhere (i.e., from say $b$ to $b+c$, where both $b$ and $c$ could be arbitrary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing $x=a\sinh t$ in the integral,
\begin{equation}
 I=\int_\beta^{\gamma}e^{ika\cosh t}\,dt
\end{equation} 
where $\beta=\sinh^{-1}b/a$ and $\gamma=\sinh^{-1}(b+c)/a$. These kinds of integrals are related to incomplete Bessel functions. Their properties are described by Jones in [Incomplete Bessel functions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9C572E5CE44E9E0DE8630755DF99ABAC/S0013091505000490a.pdf/incomplete-bessel-functions-i.pdf) and its companion paper. In particular, for $0<\sigma<\pi$
\begin{equation}
 H_0^{(1)}(ka,w)=\frac{2}{i\pi}\int_w^{\infty+i\sigma}e^{ika\cosh t}\,dt
\end{equation} 
Then
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{2}{i\pi}\left[ H_0^{(1)}(ka,\beta)- H_0^{(1)}(ka,\gamma) \right]
\end{equation} 
It can also be expressed as
\begin{equation}
 I= K_0(-ika,\beta)- K_0(-ika,\gamma)
\end{equation}
where many properties of the incomplete Bessel function $K_0(z,w)$ are given in the cited reference (series expansion, asymptotics...).

Comment: Ah, what a wonderful substitution. Thanks so much, that is it! As a minor thing, it seems I would have to change the integration limits since for $x$ to run from $b$ to $b+c$, I need to let $t$ run from something like ${\rm arsinh}(b/a)$. But that's a minor thing. Thank you again!

Comment: What still confuses me is that the integral needs to run on a line with ${\rm Im}(t)>0$ (that's how I interpret the $i \sigma$ thing?). After the substitution, the integral is strictly on the real line though. What's up with that?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake on the integration limits, corrected now.

Comment: This can be viewed as writing that the integral on a closed contour of a holomorphic function in the complex plane is zero (residue theorem). This contour is made of 3 components  1) from $\beta$ to $\gamma$ on the real axis, 2) from $\gamma$ to $\infty +i\sigma$ and 3) from  $\infty +i\sigma$ to $\beta$.

Comment: Okay, that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider function:

$$y=\sqrt{x^2+a^2} \ln e^{\sqrt {x^2 +a^2}}$$

$$y'=\frac{x}{\sqrt {x^2+a^2}}.(e^ {\sqrt{x^2+a^2}})(1+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})$$

Now compare this with the relation in question we get:

$$k=-[\frac {\ln x(1+\sqrt{x^2+a^2})}{\sqrt {x^2+a^2}}+1]i$$

This is condition for initial relation to be integrable.